# Как вывести статус выполнения функции в шаблон HTML в Django

Tags: python, django

Подскажите: есть шаблон, есть форма в которой я получаю определенные данные. При нажатии на кнопку в форме, данные обрабатываются во views, после обработки функция возвращает результат, например: "Все ок, задача выполнена без ошибок" или "Не ок, есть ошибки такие-то".

Вопрос: Как отобразить статус выполнения в шаблоне?

Я так понимаю, что страница уже отрендерина и, чтобы не обновлять страницу, мне нужно отобразить статус, что все ок, например.

Может есть какие-то методы у forms или еще какие-либо инструменты?

Comment: Так можно сделать или необходимо редиректить на новую страницу где и отобразить статус задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может это вам поможет:

```
from django.contrib import messages
        
    
    def foo(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            objectform = ObjectForm(request.POST)
            if objectform.is_valid():
                objectform.save()
                messages.success(request, ('Данные успешно добавлены!'))
                return redirect("/")
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Ошибка сохранения формы.')
```

Шаблон:

```
        {% if messages %}
            <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
```